# Why do I get the error message : doubled attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

why do I get here the error message: Doubled Attribute? I guess this means, there are more than one Attributes with the same name and value.

```
 XElement XMLRun = new XElement("RessourceAttribute");

 foreach (var kvp in Run) //kvp = KeyValuePair<string,string> and Run = List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
 {
    XAttribute aKey = new XAttribute("name", kvp.Key);
    XAttribute aValue = new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value);
    XMLRun.Add(aKey, aValue);       
 }

 XMLE.Add(XMLRun);
```

On every step there should be this two new Attributes generated and then added on the parent node. I am pretty sure the problem is here, because the Attributenames must be different. The error occurs on my Enterprise Architect AddIn. Is there a possibility that the new generated Attributes have different names?

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions - Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting is fairly basic and it makes it harder to tell variables and types apart in your code.

Comment: Also, you're looping over a list. For every element in the list, you're adding the attributes `name` and `value` to **the same `<ResourceAttribute>` element** (stored in `XMLRun`). They're obviously doubled unless `Run` only has one element. Maybe you meant to create the element and add it to its parent inside the loop as well?

Comment: (I kind of smell an XY problem here. Can you show some dummy input data and what the resulting XML should look like for it? Make sure to simplify your code so it's as self-contained as possible.)

Comment: I changed the Names, so its better to read. You guessed it right in your second comment, thats what I meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems fairly trivial to discover that if `Run` contains any more than one pair, you will receive an error. Given:

```
var Run = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "1", "a" },
    { "2", "b" },
    { "3", "c" },
};
```

Your code would then produce the invalid XML:

```
<ResourceAttribute name="1" value="a"
                   name="2" value="b"
                   name="3" value="c" />
```

Tough to say without some example XML. Perhaps you meant to have a lot of `<ResourceAttribute ...>` elements?

```
foreach (var pair in Run)
{
    XMLE.Add(
        new XElement("ResourceAttribute",
            new XAttribute("key", pair.Key),
            new XAttribute("value", pair.Value)
        )
    );
}
```

Or did you mean to place those attributes on a sub-element?

```
    // replace original loop body
    XMLRun.Add(new XElement("Run", XMLRunAttributeK, XMLRunAttributeV));
```

Or literally name the attributes based on their name?

```
    // replace original loop body
    XMLRun.Add(new XAttribute(pair.Key, pair.Value));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well if the `Run` list is like this:

```
"foo": "bar"
"foo2": "bar2"
```

You are doing something like that:

```
<ResourceAttribute name="foo" value="bar" name="foo2" value="bar2" />
```

Which is, indeed, illegal due to an attribute appearing twice...

What are you trying to do?

Comment: You got it right. I thought the loop would generate a new attribute on every step so the Output look like: <ResourceAttribute name="foo" value="bar" /><ResourceAttribute name="foo2" value="bar2" />

Comment: You need to put the XElement creation and addition into the loop then. @user7116 posted the right answer for you :)